# Existence of non-split sequence of non abelian group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a non abelian group such that $G$ contains non-zero elements of finite order. 
Does there exist some short exact non-split sequence:

$$
1\to A\to D\to G\to 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

There exist a free group $F$ and an epimorphism $F\to G$. This cannot split, because a subgroup of a free group is free, so it has no nonidentity element of finite order.